# How do I use UPDATE FROM with JOINs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

In our application we have users that are identified by email addresses. Each user can store a series of settings for the various pages of our application. I am attempting to copy the settings for one page from one user to another using a straight SQL Update query. The data is stored in Postgresql.

So far I have this:-

```
UPDATE user_settings SET value=adminuser.value FROM (
    SELECT value FROM user_settings
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id=user_settings.user_id
        WHERE users.emailaddress='joe@foo.com' AND user_settings.page='test'
) adminuser
WHERE user_id=60 AND page='test';
```

The obvious problem is that the user_id to be updated is hardcoded. I tried this:-

```
UPDATE user_settings SET value=adminuser.value FROM (
    SELECT value FROM user_settings
        INNER JOIN users ON users.id=user_settings.user_id
        WHERE users.emailaddress='joe@foo.com' AND user_settings.page='test'
) adminuser
WHERE users.emailaddress='fred@foo.com' AND user_settings.page='test';
```

But Postgresql didn't want to know. How can I perform a join on the table to be updated so that I can access the emailaddress field?

Comment: are you trying to copy email address from users to user_settings?

Comment: @KyleUp No, I'm trying to copy what is in user_settings.value I'll edit my question to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you just missing the table name in the FROM list?

```
UPDATE user_settings SET value=adminuser.value FROM (
    SELECT value FROM user_settings usa
        INNER JOIN users ua ON ua.id=usa.user_id
        WHERE ua.emailaddress='joe@foo.com' AND usa.page='test'
) adminuser, 
users 
WHERE 
users.emailaddress='fred@foo.com' AND user_settings.page='test'
AND users.id=user_settings.user_id;
```

(BTW: it's much more easy to get answers for this kind of questions if you take the time to provide the SQL script to create a dummy schema with some data to try it out. Without that, is more difficult and painful to answer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works great. I'll remember your tip about giving a dummy schema for next time. Out of curiosity, it looks like your query is doing a cross join. Is it possible to express this as an inner join?

Comment: @blackNBUK Yes, it could be an inner join. I'm not sure if that's better. What do you want to happen if there is no record in user_settings matching your admin user?

Comment: Hmmm, I hadn't really thought about that as this is just an internal tool, however it might get exposed to users in the future. If there is no record in user_settings for the admin user then I think the best thing to do would be to clear the user_settings value for the destination user. Either deleting the row or setting the value to null would work for clearing it.

Answer (score -1):

See if this works.

```
UPDATE user_settings SET value= 
    (select top 1 Value
    from
    user_settings
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id=user_settings.user_id
    WHERE users.emailaddress='joe@foo.com' AND user_settings.page='test'
)
WHERE user_id=60 AND page='test';
```

Comment: This is PostgreSQL, `TOP 1` is MS SQL syntax.